# write a jquery function which accepts params and object

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

This should be an easy one.

How to write a jquery function that gets the 'calling' object and some params.

My function code:

```
new function($) {
  $.fn.addcolor = function(param1, param2, param3, param4) {
    // here i would like to retrieve the 'caller' object (div.foo in this case)

  }
} (jQuery);
```

My code that 'calls' the function:

```
$('div.foo').click(function() {
  $(this).addcolor(1, 2, 3, 4);
});
```

I can get the params no problemo, but I want to get the content of the div.foo in the function and add some content it.

Comment: Remove `new` from your wrapper function.

Comment: Not really an answer to my question. However now I am curious. :) Why should I remove new?

Comment: When I remove new i get an js error on the page: Uncaught Syntax Error Unexpected token (

Comment: Instead, wrap the function in parentheses: `(function($) { ... })(jQuery);`

Comment: That works. Can you please explain the difference / upside of not using new?

Comment: It's more correct.  `new` will create a new instance of your function (as a class), which is then discarded.

Comment: @PeeHaa - It appears as though you're using the anonymous function like a constructor, which returns a new instance of the object it constructs. Only you have no need for the object, so it is just being discarded. I imagine this is more work behind the scenes than simply invoking an anonymous function and disregarding its `undefined` return value. *EDIT: As Slaks noted above.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `this`.

jQuery plugins in `$.fn` are normal methods on the `$` prototype.  (jQuery assigns `$.fn` to `$.prototype`)
Like any other method, you can get the context in which it was invoked using `this`.

Comment: OMG so easy. Shame on me for not trying! Thanks for nice explanation!

Answer (score 2):

In your `addcolor` plugin, `this` will represent the same jQuery object against which your plugin was called.

```
 // v---jQuery object
$(this).addcolor(1, 2, 3, 4);

(function($) {
  $.fn.addcolor = function(param1, param2, param3, param4) {
    // here "this" is the same object
    // this[ 0 ] to get the first DOM element
    // this.each(function(...   to iterate over the collection
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery plugin functions that element is referenced by this.

```
function($) {
  $.fn.addcolor = function(param1, param2, param3, param4) {
    // here i would like to retrieve the 'caller' object (div.foo in this case)
    var divcontent = $(this).html();
  }
} (jQuery);
```

Comment: There's no need to wrap `$(this)` inside the plugin since `this` is a reference to the jQuery object itself.

Comment: True, that call to jQuery can be avoided. With other variables I find it usually safer to wrap it just to make sure that I am actually handling a jQuery object though.

Answer (score 1):

this.whatever is one way...

There is also an arguments object that you can call.  ie: arguments.length or arguments["parm"]

Answer (score 0):

To extend jQuery I used:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        addcolor: function(param1, param2, param3, param4) {
            return this.empty().append(something);
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: What's the difference between your code and mine. (e.g. extend vs plugin name)?

Comment: None, I'm just showing, that you could use 'this' in function.